# not getting errorElementClass

Tags: knockout.js

Scenerio:I have added validation to observable-array , eg is about a observable field in observable array
      eg:

```
this.field = ko.observable().extend({
           required: { params: true, message: "field is required." },
           digit: { params: true, message: "field must be number." },
           min: { params: 0, message: "field must be between 0 to 9999." },
           max: { params: 9999, message: "field must be between 0 to 9999." }
       });
```

Also initialize the validations:

```
 ko.validation.init({
           registerExtenders: true,
           messagesOnModified: false,
           insertMessages: false,
           decorateElement: true,
           errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error',
           errorMessageClass: 'field-validation-error'
       });
```

But not getting `errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error'`,for other validations except required validations Note:It is taking class=valid for other validation rule violation,but error message is displayed '

Answer (score 0):

I have setup similar things in  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLX3U/13/):

```
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error',
    errorMessageClass: 'field-validation-error'
});

function Money() {
    this.Amount = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            params: true,
            message: "field is required."
        },
        digit: {
            params: true,
            message: "field must be number."
        },
        min: {
            params: 0,
            message: "field must be between 0 to 9999."
        },
        max: {
            params: 9999,
            message: "field must be between 0 to 9999."
        }
    });

    this.onSubmit = function (e) {
        return this.Amount.isValid();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Money());
```

try this in FF
I would suggest checking following steps

1. reference to script files in following order

   - jquery
   - knockout
   - knockout-validation
2. make sure ko.validations.init call at the very top in domReady
3. Version mis match is not there. latest ko.validation seems to working with knockout 3.0